# Discord bot commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've made a discord bot using python and I'd like to add a bug reporting command and some other commands so I was wondering how I could do this. For example User types: /report_bug and the bot responds: describe the bug. and then the User types in the bug. How could this be possible?

Here's a small snippet of the response code:

```py
def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == 'report_bug':
        return 'Describe the bug'
        #so here's where I'd like to take user input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything after `return`ing but assuming you just want to know how to get input:

1. Just add it as an argument to your command instead of making the bot ask for additional input afterwards. This makes the most sense, is the most user-friendly, and is the least pain to implement.
2. Use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) with a `check`.
3. Show a `Modal` where they can type whatever they want to.

Official examples for slash commands (with arguments): https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py

Official example for a Modal: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/modals/basic.py